# Use GROUP BY with SELECT CASE WHEN statement

Tags: sql, oracle, exasol

I have a table like:

```
ORDER_DATE | ORDER_ID | ORDER_AMOUNT
2020-11-07 | 1        | 40
2020-11-07 | 1        | 60
2021-04-01 | 2        | 100
```

From 2020-07-01 to 2020-12-31 the sales tax was reduced from 19% to 16% due to Covid.

Now I need to know the gross amount per ORDER_ID. The result should be:

```
ORDER_ID | ORDER_AMOUNT
1        | 116
2        | 119
```

My code so far:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ORDER_DATE BETWEEN '2020-07-01' AND '2020-12-31'
                THEN SUM(ORDER_AMOUNT) * 1.16
            WHEN (ORDER_DATE < '2020-07-01' OR ORDER_DATE > '2020-12-31')
                THEN SUM(ORDER_AMOUNT) * 1.19 
            ELSE 0
       END AS 'gross_amount'
--
FROM my_dwh_table
--
GROUP BY
        CASE WHEN ORDER_DATE BETWEEN '2020-07-01' AND '2020-12-31'
                THEN SUM(ORDER_AMOUNT) * 1.16
            WHEN (ORDER_DATE < '2020-07-01' OR ORDER_DATE > '2020-12-31')
                THEN SUM(ORDER_AMOUNT) * 1.19 
            ELSE 0
        END
;
```

but I get this error in DBeaver:

```
SQL Error [42000]: set function in group by clause
```

How can I use the CASE WHEN statement for calculating the different sales taxes with the GROUP BY on ORDER_ID? Where is the error in my code?

Comment: CASE goes inside the SUM, not the other way round.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to phrase this with the `CASE` as an argument to the `SUM()`:

```
SELECT ORDER_ID,
       SUM(CASE WHEN ORDER_DATE BETWEEN '2020-07-01' AND '2020-12-31'
                THEN ORDER_AMOUNT * 1.16
                ELSE ORDER_AMOUNT * 1.19 
           END) AS gross_amount
FROM my_dwh_table
GROUP BY ORDER_ID;
```

No `ORDER BY` is needed.

Note:  This assumes that `ORDER_DATE` is never `NULL` (hence no need for an `ELSE 0` and that `'2020-07-01'` is a valid date on your system.  I would normally use `DATE '2020-07-01'` for a date constant.

Comment: Thanks, but this sums up all ORDER_IDs, not per unique ORDER_ID?

Comment: Try `FROM my_dwh_table GROUP BY ORDER_ID;` at the end.